# Is that estimation right on $B_1(0)$?

Tags: solution-verification, estimation

> > Is the estimation
> >     $$
> > \frac{n}{2}-1 < \sum_{i=1}^n\frac{1}{1+x_i^2}
> > $$
> >     right, if $x\in B_1(0)\subset\mathbb{R}^n$? I guess $B_1(0)$ is the open unit ball.

Anyhow it is:

$$
\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{1}{1+x_i^2}<\frac{n}{2}
$$
on $B_1(0)$, so

$$
\frac{n}{2}-\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{1}{1+x_i^2}>0.
$$

Then 
$$
\frac{n}{2}-\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{1}{1+x_i^2}-1
$$
does not have to be negative, I think.

Comment: You have $x_i^2 \leqslant 1$, hence $\dfrac{1}{1+x_i^2} \geqslant \dfrac12$.

Comment: Ah, of course because the denominator is smaller then 2 (i only need $>$ because its the open ball).